# Apply tailwind inline styles to components imported from a library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am building a React component library using TailwindCSS and I was wondering if there was a way to have the styles for the library's components (in `node_modules`) get compiled with the consuming app's styles, without having every app have the relative path to the components added to the `content` field of its `tailwind.config.js`. Having looked at the docs for presets it seems that if I just add it to the library's preset just it gets overwritten by the app's custom config.

Comment: You could consider exporting a function that the consumer must use to defined their Tailwind configuration. This would then allow you to modify their `content` array from within your own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up  doing what @Wongjn suggested, and created a function that modifies a custom Tailwind config to add the module to the `content` field.

Comment: I would like to know how to accomplish this. I get the idea of this, but having difficulty understanding how to implement.

Comment: @Vippy I created a function that accepts a Tailwind Config object as a parameter, and then pushes a custom `node_modules` path into the `content` field. However, this might not work with package managers that use a different `node_modules` structure to npm, and I'm not sure of a better way to do it.